# Neo4j Cypher check if node is ancestor of child node

Tags: neo4j, cypher, spring-data-neo4j

I have a following class:

```
@NodeEntity
public class Product {

    private final static String CONTAINS = "CONTAINS";

    @GraphId
    private Long id;

    @RelatedTo(type = CONTAINS, direction = Direction.INCOMING)
    private Set<Product> parentProducts = new HashSet<>();

}
```

I'm trying to implement a method:

```
public boolean isProductAncestor(Product productId, Product childProductId) {
    //some Cypher query
}
```

that will check if `productId` is an ancestor(any depth up to the root) of `childProductId`.

I need a Cypher query for it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This query finds the path between them:

```
MATCH path=(p:Product)-[:CONTAINS*]->(m:Product)
WHERE id(p) = {idp} AND id(m) = {idm}
RETURN path LIMIT 1;
```

If you get a result, that means that `m` is an ancestor of `p`.  If you get nothing, there's no relationship between them.